# Does Azure Networking/ VNet, Load Balancer, Application Gateway, Traffic Manager always need VM?

Tags: azure, networking, virtual-machine, azure-web-app-service

I am starting to read documentation on Azure Networking and every single example evrywhere gives an example of 2 Virutal Machines and then explains be it subnet, Traffic Manager, Load Balancer etc

Maybe its a dumb question But Can I do Load Balancing for Azure App Services, Azure DB, Storage Account etc without Virtual Machines ?

Answer (score 1):

For PaaS services you cannot use load balancing for the most part, because it makes no sense. you would need to replicate data on your own. if you are to load balance between PaaS services. besides thats the idea behind PaaS, you dont have to care about PaaS. it just works.

But for webapps (and it makes sense) you can use load balancers\application gateway\traffic manager to balance load.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand network design and build a theory behind it.
Now, load balancing is required for HA and redundancy in a network, beyond which you extract the capability of the load balancer based on your requirements/Application.

So, PaaS services are not managed by completely by the user. You are paying a premium for using them and they will come with a built-in redundancy which you should opt for during deployment.

Load Balancing on Azure is Primarily "configurable" for IaaS only.